# window.open works when at the start of the function but not at the end

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, window

window.open works when at the start of the function but not at the end .this one works

```
render = function() { 
  window.open("https://xxxx=singhi"); 
  var yhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  yhttp.open('GET', 'url', false); 
  yhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'AR-JWT ' + res); 
  yhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
  yhttp.send(); 
  const tit = yhttp.responseText; 
  document.write(tit); 
  document.write(tit.entries[0].values["Remedy Login ID"]); 
  remedyid=tit.entries[0].values["Remedy Login ID"]; 
};
```

this one doesn't

```
render = function() { 
  var yhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  yhttp.open('GET', 'url', false); 
  yhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'AR-JWT ' + res); 
  yhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  yhttp.send(); 
  const tit=yhttp.responseText; 
  document.write(tit);
  remedyid = tit.entries[0].values["Remedy Login ID"]; 
  window.open("https://xxxx=singhi");
};
```

Comment: Consider using `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`? --- Also, please may you add what you mean by "this one doesn't"? What do you expect to happen? What happens at the moment?

Comment: window.open opens the url in first case but not in the case of 2nd where it is placed at the end of the function, weird

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? Please make sure the examples are [mcve]s.

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: Then can you make sure we can run your examples? There's a bunch of missing stuff, most of which might be irrelevant.

Comment: What I've isolated so far is that it works before the ajax call and not after the ajax call, tried with synchronous ajax call as well

Comment: I don’t think there’s such a thing as a sync Ajax call. Also try swapping the XMLHttpRequest with fetch?

Comment: i have fixed the issue, the problem was with that my ajax API call was synchronous, changed it to asynchronous

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer showing what you changed?

Answer (score 0):

just removed false from below, i had it synchronous for some reason before , but now i needed it to be asynchronou yhttp.open('GET', 'url',false);